# How to automate publish in a CI environment?

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

We are using `lerna` to manage a monorepo and we want to automate the publishing process:

1. The developer makes changes in one of the packages in the monorepo
2. The CI detects that changes have been made
3. The CI builds the package, the patch level is automatically incremented, and the new package is published, tags are pushed to git, etc.

To avoid infinite cycles ( build -> tag -> push -> build -> tag -> ...), the CI should only build  if there are indeed changes  - hence step 2

1. How can one do that with `lerna`? Is 'from-git' an option?
2. Is there any other "best practice" how to use `lerna` in a CI environment?